# Alternative to Jing

Tags: screen-capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best software for desktop recording?](https://superuser.com/questions/6801/what-is-the-best-software-for-desktop-recording)

Do you know of any alternative software for jing: www.jingproject.com/
Its a screencasting tool which you can easily used to upload and share what's on your screen.
I like sharing images from screen capture but the video produced in jing is .swf which is not allowed in youtube.
Ive also tried camstudio but I had problems with it. My monitor suddenly became wavy(its as if there's water in my monitor and I can't see anything.)
Do you know of any free screencasting tool that I could use to share images and videos on youtube?

Comment: there are already a couple of threads here (which is the best screen capturing software) dealing with this question.

Comment: @Molly Please vote to close duplicates, and don't edit the duplicate into the question text. It is done automatically and means we have to edit the question twice.

Comment: haha, you'd think someone with 31,297+ points would have figured that out by now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**ScreenToaster**](http://www.screentoaster.com/) may be just what you are looking for.

It is free and has built-in functionlity for uploading HD videos directly into YouTube.

[image]